# Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I installed all dependencies and packages. No error exist in it. My drawer navigation does not function. Please provide me some helpful hints. I got stuck in. It's not working as expected. Basically I have two Navigation file and App file which is shown below.

This is the code Navigation.js file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import SignIn from '../Screens/SignIn';
import Home from '../Screens/Home';
import ForgotPassword from '../Screens/ForgotPassword';
import ChangePassword from '../Screens/ChangePassword';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const CustomDrawer = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            padding: 20,
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
              BusGo Captain App
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 50,
          backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
          padding: 20,
        }}></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

function DrawerRoutes() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          title: 'Home',
          drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
            <Icon name="home" size={size} color="black" />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <RootSiblingParent>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />

        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DrawerRoutes" component={DrawerRoutes} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </RootSiblingParent>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

This the app.js file, which is the main file.
App.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigation from './Src/Navigation/Navigation'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Navigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the drawer is working, you just need to go to drawer screen,
add below code to go to the drawer screen, check drawer after clicking **SignIn**

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate('DrawerRoutes');
        }}>
        <Text>SignIn</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
};
```

if you need the drawer to be on the first screen, put drawer screen first

```
function Navigation() {
    return (
        <RootSiblingParent>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="DrawerRoutes" component={DrawerRoutes} />
                <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
                
                <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </RootSiblingParent>
    );
}
```

Comment: The issue has yet to be rectified. Drawer navigation is functional but not visible in my application.